# Reading ".properties" file in Android taking too much of time

Tags: android, performance, android-assets

I am reading a `.properties` file in android which is stored in assets folder. My `.properties` file has almost 8000-9000 key value pairs. For loading it is taking almost 4 minutes. Below is my code for reading the `.properties` file.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
AssetManager assets = resources.getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = assets.open("details.properties");
props.load(inputStream);
```

When executing line `props.load(inputStream)` it is taking almost 4 minutes to complete. I am using Eclipse and executing my code in MOTO G mobile in developer mode.

Below is my sample `.properties` file values.

`AB=HELLO
 CD=WORLD`
like this there were 8000 key value pairs.
Please let me know is there any problem in my code or any other way to do it fast. Thanks!!

Comment: You should use a database table, to handle so many data.

Comment: Is the properties file something you're editing at runtime? If so, have you considered making a hardcoded lookup table, or maybe a databse table? Do you have to load all the properties up front? Can they be loaded by a service at startup?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried executing the code without debugger attached?  Debugger slows down memory access by 10 times.
2. Have you consider using String.xml instead of using a plain file?